# JVIsualVM looses local Java process from list

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm

I am using JDK 1.7.0_60 and I have a Java process. I was always monitoring my process using VisualVM, but few days ago my Virtual Machine crashed, because of some other side effects. After that fact, VisualVM lost exising process from certain list. When I try to add localhost:3333, it shows the error:

`Cannot connect to localhost:3333 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:3333/jmxrmi`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add it to VisualVM if it's running on your local. It will be listed automatically under `Applications -> Local` when you open VisualVM with the application running in background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I said VisualVM lost existing process from certain list. So your answer is unused.

I cleared the cache data and it solved this problem.